# UIAlertViewcontroller is not being popped before going to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want after signup the alert controller should pop up and then go the loginFirstViewController but this is not going to happen why?? it only goes to loginfirstviewcontroller instead of poping up alert controller

```
     if error == nil {



                FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
                })



                print("You have successfully signed up")
                //Goes to the Setup page which lets the user take a photo for their profile picture and also chose a username




                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Successful!", message: "Email Verification link sent", preferredStyle: .alert)


                let alertActionOkay = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default)

                    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginFirstViewController")

                    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)



                  alertController.addAction(alertActionOkay)

               self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
```

Comment: you want to naviget to another VC if user click the OK button or else

Comment: You are presenting alertController on ViewController before viewController is Presented. You can try presenting the alert on the previous controller on okay action of alert push new viewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You directly opened new viewcontroller to prevent this you should add completion handler for uialertaction. When the user press ok button you can open other viewcontroller

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Successful!", message: "Email Verification link sent", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let alertActionOkay = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default) { (action) in
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginFirstViewController")
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    alertController.addAction(alertActionOkay)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```